# "Where Bob and Bob alone is ..." with or without commas?

Tags: commas

Does grammar dictate the need for commas in the phrase "... where Bob and Bob alone is ..."? In other words, is it necessary to add commas around "and Bob alone":

> ... where Bob, and Bob alone, is ...

Comment: Punctuation; isn't exactly my, strong point but I. Would place "and Bob alone" between, commas.

Comment: The commas are required, in my opinion, because the phrase 'and Bob alone' is _parenthetical_. That is it is not part of the main structure of the sentence which would have pretty much the same meaning without the extra phrase. You could, alternatively, put it in brackets.

Comment: @BoldBen Agreed, but intuitively the commas may seem unnecessary because we often don't pause when saying this aloud.

Comment: OTOH, some do pause for emphasis: "Bob ... *and Bob alone* ..."

Comment: @Barmar To me commas, indeed any punctuation marks, only have an incidental relationship with pauses in most contexts: they are concerned with the logical structure of the text. The pauses (or breaths) that we take are the vocal equivalent of punctuation and usually serve to structure the speech in terms of its meaning.

Comment: @BoldBen That's true, but since proper comma usage is often fuzzy, it's most intuitive to equate them with vocal pauses.